# Taylor series problem!

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

How can I proceed if I want to find a $M$ (non negative) so that $\sum_{n=M+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}<10^{-8}$

Can I use this taylor [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLuUB.png)??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not quite since you don't have a description of what $C$ is in that formula. You could use the formula for the Lagrange Remainder https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html as it tells you that $C = f^{(n + 1)}(t) = e^{t}$ where $t$ is between 0 and 1. And thus $C \leq e^1 < 3$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=M+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} &= \frac{1}{(M+1)!} \left(1 + \frac{1}{(M+2)}  + \frac{1}{(M+2)(M+3)} + \dots \right) \\
 &<\frac{1}{(M+1)!} \left(1 + \frac{1}{(M+2)}  + \frac{1}{(M+2)^2} + \dots \right) \\
 &\le\frac{2}{(M+1)!},  \quad \text{ if } M+2 \ge 2
\end{align}
Since $\frac{2}{12!} < 10^{-8}$, $M=11$ will do the trick.